# Excel VBA Open File (error handling)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to account for a case when the user does not find a file to open:

```
Dim fn As String
fn = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files,.", 1, "Select a file", , False)

If fn = False Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```

This does what I want it to when a file is not chosen.

But when the user *does* choose a file, this If statement creates an error. Can anyone tell me the proper way to accomplish this?

Comment: If you would have pressed the magic key F1 in Excel you would have got your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function does not return the boolean `False`, but the **string** `"False"`, as it will cast the variant from the function into your variable type, so your test should be

```
If fn = "False" Then
```

(changed explanation - thanks @SiddharthRout)

Comment: `Application.GetOpenFilename` returns a variant

Comment: @siddharthRout: changed explanation of what happens in FancyCorndog's code

Comment: Sean. I don't mean to be picky but this statement `The function does not return the boolean False, but the string "False"` is incorrect :( When nothing is selected it does return a boolean else it returns a string and that is the reason why we declare the variable `fn` as variant.

Comment: @SiddharthRout, the function as written will cause the return value to be cast into a string. The test of `"False"=False` evaluates as true, so the test works on a cancel, but fails when comparing anything other than a string that can be interpreted as a boolean

Comment: Try: `Debug.Print "True" = True, "False" = False, "0" = False, "-1" = True` and see how many `True` results you get

Comment: I understand that part but if you check the Excel's help `This method returns the selected file name or the name entered by the user. The returned name may include a path specification. If MultiSelect is True, the return value is an array of the selected file names (even if only one filename is selected). Returns False if the user cancels the dialog box.` We don't need to handle the output per se. If we declare the variable as variant then Excel automatically handles it appropriately.

Comment: I am not saying that your method is incorrect. I am just saying that the statement `he function does not return the boolean False, but the string "False"` is incorrect. It does return a boolen in case of Cancel which can be converted to a "String" like you have done :)

Comment: @Fancydog: Seems like you didn't get my point. You have declared `Dim fn As String` Now try this `fn = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files,.", 1, "Select a file", , True)` instead of `fn = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files,.", 1, "Select a file", , False)` Notice the `Multiselect` is set to true. What happens?

Answer (score 3):

If you check Excel's inbuilt help, you will notice that `Application.GetOpenFilename` returns a variant. So all you have to do is declare `fn` as `Variant`,

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim fn As Variant

    fn = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files,.", 1, "Select a file", , False)

    If fn = False Then Exit Sub

    MsgBox fn
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
If fn = False Then
```

To

```
If CStr(fn) = "False" Then
```

Comment: Why do you coerce a string to a string? Just write `If fn = "False" Then`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett. Thanks. Good point. When I was playing with it, I didn't test that out.